# Undesired equal sign in beamer using \dimexpr

Tags: beamer, calculations, dimension-expressions

I'm using the following script in beamer to locate our logo at the right-most corner of all pages in the presentation,

```
\begin{textblock}{5}(10.0, \dimexpr 0.5\headheight - 7.5pt )
   \includegraphics[width=40pt]{logo.png}
\end{textblock}
```

The placement of the textblock in the page is fine, however there is an undesired equal sign (see added image) in the page. It's the first time I use `\dimexpr`, do I make a mistake?

[image]

I think this undesired equal sign comes from `\dimexpr 0.5\headheight - 7.5pt` this part of script. Because when I replace it with, for example, `1`, the equal sign goes.

I just tried to do something `\dimexpr 15pt - 7.5pt` it still gives an undesired equal sign.

Comment: Please, convert it to a full [Minimal (non-)Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You probably also get some compilation errors: never overlook them.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I have some compilation errors too. However, my deadline is coming and I pretend like there no `warning`s. I really wish I had time to create a perfect template.

Comment: Error messages and warnings are different things; an error can lead to very unexpected results, as you found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the starred version of the `textblock` environment. This way, you can indicate the unit and, when the `calc` package is loaded, you can do your usual `calc` computations.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{textpos}
\title{Topic name}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(10pt,\dimexpr0.5\headheight - 7.5pt)
   \includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `testblock` doesn't accept values with a unit. You have to strip it:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}%% only for demo
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\foo{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.5\headheight - 5pt\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{textblock}{5}(10.0,\foo)
   \includegraphics[width=40pt]{logo.png}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

However, instead of using `textblock` you should redefine your header which is possible with the default macros which beamer provides.

Comment: This manipulation generates an undesired `@pt 0.5=`